# need to know the reason why the below html files are not opening in R

Tags: html, r

The following is working:

```
url_a <- getURL("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6494/000119312504029815/d8k.htm")

dfx_a <- htmlParse(url_a)
```

The following is not working:

```
url_b <- getURL("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1639947/000104746916009939/a2226912zs-11.htm")

dfx_b <- htmlParse(url_b)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Is it php coding or which technology?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the S part in http in the second url.

it should be https?